# timeout when trying to get all frames Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting a HTMLElement from a list of frames using this line of code

```
var confirmElement = ActiveBrowser.Frames["scheduleAndSend_iframe"].Find.ById("btnConfirm").Children[0];
```

However when I come back to retun the whole list of frames from the same browser using this

```
var framesList = ActiveBrowser.Frames;
```

it crashes at this level

```
var frames = Driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iFrame"));
```

and the returned message is the following :

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/b7a93163-6a8e-4747-874d-2fb79a55091e/elements timed out after 60 seconds.
----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
```

Any help please? 
Thank you

Comment: What version of IE? What version of IEDriver? What version of Selenium?

Comment: I'm using Firefox v31.0, Webdriver 2.42 , Selenium 2.42

Comment: You need to be upgrading to v2.43 - because support for Firefox 31 is only in version >2.43

Comment: Can this option be a solution for my issue?

Comment: Not sure what you expect to happen if the version you have doesn't support the Firefox version you are using...? It may not be the solution, but it's a quick win if it *was* the reason.

Comment: Okay I'll upgrade Webdriver and see what will happen, Thanks :)

Comment: got the same problem, it is not a matter of updating Webdriver